# MongoDB Atlas Trigger - Changes could not be saved. Only [uri, clusterId, etc.] are allowed config options

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas, mongodb-realm

I am trying to setup an Atlas Trigger but am getting the following error when trying to save. I am on the free shared cluster M0 on MongoDB 4.4.10

> only [uri, clusterId, clusterName, clusterType, clusterSize,
> clusterUpdated, dbUsername, dbPassword, lastUpdated,
> wireProtocolEnabled, regionName, groupName, orgName,
> namespacePreimageConfigs, readPreference, readPreferenceTagSets, sync,
> sync_query, connect_through_mesh] are allowed config options

The following image is of my Trigger Source Details.

[image: Here are my Trigger Source Details]

My function just consists of two simple console logs for now as just a test:

```
console.log(changeEvent.fullDocument);
console.log(changeEvent.fullDocumentBeforeChange);
```

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated and thanks for your time!

**UPDATE:**
After turning off both full document and document preimage it saves just fine, however, I need both in order to execute my desired functionality...